# HTML template for selecting fields from one list to another and pass to Django view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to UI development so not sure what the template I am looking for is called. I tried searching in the web with few posts with no results.

I have currently over 60 fields to select, so I want to provide a list of these 60 fields and user can select the required ones to another list, [something like this, which many professional sites use to select our options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWhq9.jpg)

Any lead for designing this kind of template will be very useful, specially with source code or some reference links. Thanks in advance

EDIT: my template code:

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>Select your fields for analysis:</h3><br><br><br>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldBox">

        <div class="column">
            <ul class="field-list1" style="list-style-type:none">
                {% for field in field_names %}
                    <li><p> {{ field.fieldname }} </p></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <ul class="field-list3" style="list-style-type:none">
                <p> Selected fields </p>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <ul class="field-list2" style="list-style-type:none">
                <li><button type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button></li><br><br>
                <li><button type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12"><br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right; margin-right: 150px">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>&nbsp; OK
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
.fieldBox {
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 150px;
   }
.field-list1 {height:400px; width:30%; float:left; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}
.field-list2 {height:150px; margin-top:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:65px;}
.field-list3 {height:400px; width:30%; float:right; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide any code you have already written.  We can help you debug code, but this site isn't for others to write your code from scratch.

Comment: Agreed :) that's why I asked for some reference links to go for it. Right now I have only the template with those columns and my fields (with poor formatting :( ), but I am not sure how to select each field such as 'apple' and then click the right arrow button to push the apple to the 2nd column so that it can be sent to my view as post parameters.